# Spring Boot unit test runs the whole program

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, spring-boot-test

I would like to implement an integration test with Spring Boot. I start with the `spring-boot-starter-test` dependency, version `2.2.5.RELEASE`.

I have the following component:

```
@Component
public class MyMath {

    public int add(int a, int b) {
        return a + b;
    }

}
```

The main program looks like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Main implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }

    @Autowired
    private MyMath myMath;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(myMath.add(2, 3));
    }

}
```

It works as expected - so far, so good. I would like to add a unit test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class MyMathTest {

    @Autowired
    private MyMath myMath;

    @Test
    public void testSaveAndList() {
        assertEquals(5, myMath.add(2, 3));
    }

}
```

This also works, but according to the log it **executes the whole program**. I don't want to run the program itself, just the `MyMath.add()` function. How can I do that?

I tried the following so far:

- `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` provided the same result.
- Omitting `@SpringBootTest` results `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException`.
- Reformatting the code to have bean instead of component like below it works.

`MyMath` without annotation:

```
public class MyMath {

    public int add(int a, int b) {
        return a + b;
    }

}
```

`Main` remains the same.

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public MyMath getMyMath() {
        return new MyMath();
    }
}
```

And the test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = AppConfig.class)
public class MyMathTest {

    @Autowired
    private MyMath myMath;

    @Test
    public void testSaveAndList() {
        assertEquals(5, myMath.add(2, 3));
    }

}
```

So what I cannot do is to test a component without running the whole program. Could any help me? Thanks!

Comment: I think you won't really need anything provided by Spring to run this test. Try removing all Spring-related annotations from your test class, don't inject MyMath, rather instantiate it with `new` somewhere in the test class. As long as the @Test annotation remains, JUnit should pick it up. Try using a non-Spring test runner, more info [here](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Test-runners).

Comment: Yes, testing an add function really does not need any Spring stuff. But what if I have a component which has autowired dependencies, and I want to test it? I deliberately did not want to overcomplicate the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to refactor your code. Just keep the MyMath class as it is

```
@Component
public class MyMath {

    public int add(int a, int b) {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

Change your test class like this

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = MyMath.class)
public class MyMathTest {

    @Autowired
    private MyMath myMath;

    @Test
    public void testSaveAndList() {
        assertEquals(5, myMath.add(2, 3));
    }

}
```

This becomes a bit complex if your MyMath class has other dependencies autowired. Then you have to use mocks.

Comment: Thank you, that is what I wanted!

Answer (score 0):

If your MyMath class is so simple I would not use Spring to initialize it. There is no need and what is more important - junit should be quick. So instead of running your test with Spring Context change it to simple JUnit and create MyMath like normal object:

```
public class MyMathTest {

    private MyMath myMath = new MyMath();

    @Test
    public void testSaveAndList() {
        assertEquals(5, myMath.add(2, 3));
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Indeed I deliberately created such a simple example. The point here is not the adder but how to create unit test in Spring.

Comment: You should always ask the question if you really need a Spring to create a JUnit test. Mostly you can create object with simple constructor so your test runs faster. Tests which are annotated with SpringBootTest are considered to be an integration test.