# Run Spring Boot Unit Test with separate DB jdbcTemplate (H2) with manually created table and populated data

Tags: spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit

In our Spring Boot app, for unit tests we use the H2 In-Memory DB (the app itself uses Oracle). Our DAO class uses a simple `jdbcTemplate` for its DB operations. The unit test should create a table and populate some data in H2 (also using `jdbcTemplate`) before testing the actual DAO methods.

First, I tried creating `application-test.yml` under test/resources with

```
spring:
  h2:
    console:
      enabled: true
      path: /h2
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
    username: sa
    password: password
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

and then doing

```
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class MyTest {

        // Autowire jdbcTemplate so I can add table/data manually
        @Autowired
        private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;  

        @BeforeEach
        void setUp() throws Exception {
    
          // Set up table & data...
          String sql = "CREATE TABLE TESTTABLE ( ... )";
          String sql2 = "INSERT INTO TESTTABLE VALUES (.., ..)";
          jdbcTemplate.update(sql);
          jdbcTemplate.update(sql2);

        @Test
        void testDAO() {
          //..
        }
}
```

When I run this, the unit test **loads the entire Spring Boot app** which I don't need, and obviously complains that some expected DAO methods aren't found (I'm not using the real app's Oracle DB). I found via [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60901153/1005607) that I need to use `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` instead of `@SpringBootTest`.

But now, even with the revised annotation, the test still doesn't work. Now the error is
**java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(String)" because "this.jdbcTemplate" is null**

```
// Note new annotations to avoid the loading of entire Spring Boot app
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = JdbcTemplate.class)
public class SomeTest {
    
            // Autowire jdbcTemplate so I can add table/data manually
            @Autowired
            private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;  

            @BeforeEach
            void setUp() throws Exception {
        
              // Set up table & data...
              String sql = "CREATE TABLE TESTTABLE ( ... )";
              String sql2 = "INSERT INTO TESTTABLE VALUES (.., ..)";
              jdbcTemplate.update(sql);
              jdbcTemplate.update(sql2);

            @Test
            void testDAO() {
              //..
            }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. First, `@JdbcTest` must be used, and second, the context configuration must point to the DAO class being tested.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = AppDAO.class)
@JdbcTest
public class SomeTest {
  //..
}
```